# Use Newton's Law on Spring with Mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, free-body-diagram, spring

For SHM with a spring with mass m and uniformly stretched, its effective mass is m/3:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(spring%E2%80%93mass_system)

However, all the solutions online I can find is based on Energy. Can we use Newton's law to get the same conclusion? I tried, and get effective mass of $ \frac{m}{2}$:

Consider a tiny piece $\Delta l $ with distance l from the wall (total length of the spring is L at the time). Its acceleration is a(l). Applying F=ma: $$ F(l+\Delta l ) - F(l) = dm * a(l) = (m\frac{dl}{L}) * (a(L)\frac{l}{L})$$

Hence $$\frac{dF}{dl} = m * a(L)\frac{l }{L^2}.$$ so $$ F(l)=\frac{m}{2}*a(L)*\frac{l^2}{L^2}.$$  Hence $$F(L)=\frac{m}{2}a(L)$$

Therefore, to the object, it is as if experiencing a force of $$-kx - \frac{m}{2}*a(L).$$

The object attached to the spring has a mass M and acceleration a(L).

The effective mass is $\frac{m}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The effective mass of a spring is a trick used to speed up calculations while specifically calculating the kinetic energy possessed by a spring when its end is being extended by a constant velocity $v$ and is equal to  $\frac{m}{3}$

Since this only works for the kinetic energy of a spring, it doesn't make too much sense to try calculating its effective mass using newtons laws of motion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).